# Exam-Labs and Magento Certified Developer Exam

Tags: certification

I'm trying to take the exam for the Magento Certified Developer. I've done some researches and found this [Exam Labs website](http://exam-labs.com/exam/M70-101), and here we can try a test exam.

**I wonder if the answers provided to each question are realiable?**

Because when I came to this question today,

> **Question No : 68 - In order to successfully register and configure a new entity capable of being saved and loaded from the database, you
>   must create a model and which three of the following? (Choose three)**
>
> A. a collection class
>
> B. configuration settings in your module's config.xml
>
> C. an entry in Mage::$_registry
>
> D. a record in the eav_entity table
>
> E. a resource model
>
> F. a table in the database that will store the entity s data

The answer website provided is B,E,F. I agree with B and E. but why F is correct? shouldn't it be **D**?